# searchBar does not hide after pushing another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I created a search bar at the header view of a table:

```
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.list count]];
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

And when tap a certain row in the tableview, a new view controller will be pushed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"HEY ROW %ld", indexPath.row+1);
    ZLContainerViewController *controller = [[ZLContainerViewController alloc]init]; // a container for UIPage
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];    
}
```

However, after pushing the new view controller, the search bar is still there. How can I solve this problem?

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: You are creating a UISearchController . Try on creating a UISearchBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these two UISearchBarDelegate delegate methods should fix your problem

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Though this method didn't directly solve my problem, but "resignFirstResponder" gave me a hint. I ended up calling "resignFirstResponder" and change searchbar to hidden whenever a new view controller is pushed. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code in `viewDidLoad`.

**Swift:**

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

**Objective-C:**

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

This solved the problem for me.